# Two different system monitor apps after upgrading to 19.10

Tags: 19.10, system-monitor

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 and now there are 
[two system monitor apps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p2c3.png)

Is this a bug?  Should I remove one?  What is the best course of action to precede?  I don't want to mess anything up.

Answer (score 3):

If you right-click on each, and select "Show Details"...

Then scroll down to the "Details" section...

You will see that each has a different source:

- ubuntu-eoan-main  (this one is a deb package)
- Snap Store  (this one is a Snap package)

You can safely remove either, or even both. The presence of both is expected behavior - the Snap was added during the 19.04 cycle.

If you can't pull up details on one of them, *that's* a bug in the .desktop file. However you can still easily find both in Ubuntu Software.